# Android listview paging - aggind a footer but footer does not apear in the list

Tags: android, listview, footer

I am using a listview with paging - so I should add a listview at the end of it.
I have a code - integrated from what Ifound in the web. But I see that addFooter method is called (in the two places it is mentioned) but the footer does not appear on the screen?

Relevant code:

```
public class GlobalBookTab extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener
```

{
    private final String                mTAG                    = "GlobalBook";

```
private EditText                    mSearchEditText         = null;
private String                      mLastSearchString       = null;

private View                        mCategoriesView         = null;

private int                         mQueryPageNumber        = 1;
private ServerWrapper.SortByEnum    mLastSearchSorting      = SortByEnum.NO_SORTING;
private GlobalRecipeListAdapter     mListViewAdapter        = null;

private boolean                     mIsCategorySearch       = false;
private Recipe.CategoryEnum         mSearchCategory         = Recipe.CategoryEnum.NO_CATEGORY;

private ImageView                   mSortByRateView         = null;
private ImageView                   mSortByDifficultyView   = null;
private ImageView                   mSortByTimeView         = null;

private View                        mFooterView             = null;
private boolean                     mLoadingMore            = false;
private ListView                    mListView               = null;

private LayoutInflater              mInflater               = null;

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.global_book);

    mInflater           = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));

    mListView           = this.getListView();
    mListViewAdapter    = new GlobalRecipeListAdapter(  this, 
                                                        R.layout.recipes_list_view_entry, 
                                                        new ArrayList<Recipe>() );

    mFooterView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, false);

    setListAdapter( mListViewAdapter );
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View)
 */
public void onClick( View v )
{
    switch( v.getId() )
    {
        case R.id.searchImageViewId:
            mQueryPageNumber    = 1;
            mLastSearchSorting  = SortByEnum.NO_SORTING;
            mLastSearchString   = mSearchEditText.getText().toString();
            if( mIsCategorySearch == false )
            {
                mSearchCategory = CategoryEnum.NO_CATEGORY;
            }

            SearchButtonClicked();

        default:
            Log.e( mTAG, "Unknown clickId" );
            return;
    }
}


/**
 * Used when the search button is clicked
 */
private void SearchButtonClicked()
{
    Log.d( mTAG, "Searching for recipe - " + mSearchEditText.getText().toString() );

    performSearchBackgroundTask task = new performSearchBackgroundTask();
    task.execute();
    mFooterView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
    getListView().addFooterView( mFooterView );
}

private class performSearchBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>  
{
    ArrayList<Recipe>               mRecipes        = null;
    private ProgressDialog          Dialog          = new ProgressDialog( GlobalBookTab.this );
    private boolean                 mExecutedOK     = false;
    private ServerException.Id      mExceptionId    = ServerException.Id.Id_MAX;

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        Dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)    
    {
        if(Dialog.isShowing())
        {
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if( mExecutedOK == true )
        {
            if( mRecipes.size() == 0 )
            {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                                "No matching results",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeCategoriesVisibility( View.GONE );
                ChangeSortingVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

                if( mQueryPageNumber != 1 )
                {
                    mListViewAdapter.clear();
                }

                if( mRecipes != null )
                {
                    for( int i = 0; i < mRecipes.size(); ++i )
                    {
                        if( mRecipes.get( i ) != null )
                        {
                            mListViewAdapter.add( mRecipes.get( i ) );
                        }
                    }
                }

                mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                // Might be more results
                if( mRecipes.size() == 5 )
                {
                    mFooterView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
                    mListView.addFooterView( mFooterView );
                }
                else
                {
                    mListView.removeFooterView( mFooterView );
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch( mExceptionId )
            {
                case FAILED:
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                                    "No matching results",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case UNABLE_TO_CONNECT_TO_SERVER:
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Failed to connect to server",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground( Void... params ) 
    {
        // Do your background data fetching here
        ServerWrapper               webService  = new ServerWrapper();
        try
        {
            mRecipes = webService.SearchRecipe( mLastSearchString, 
                                                mQueryPageNumber,
                                                mLastSearchSorting,
                                                mSearchCategory );
        }
        catch( ServerException e )
        {
            mExecutedOK     = false;
            mExceptionId    = e.eId();

            return null;
        }

        mExecutedOK = true;
        return null;   
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call addFooter method prior to setAdapter for list.
Else header/footer wont be visible.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Ohhhhh I see. But After I set the adapter can I remove and add it as I like? or need to set the adapter again? or use visibility.GONE?

Comment: No need to set the adapter again (set only if the data str of the list changes completely).
Just use visibility on/off for the footer view.
that should work fine.